# Getting Exception using JAIN_SIP api in android VOIP CALL

Tags: android, voip, jain-sip

My requirement is to establish voice calls from android phone to VOIP landline phone, its perfectly working using android sip protocol API. But its not working on all android version mobiles. Now i am trying to develop using JAIN-SIP third party API.I have done every thing as per API,but i can't able to solve my problem by using this api as shown below link.

Link :https://github.com/Mobicents/restcomm-android-sdk/tree/master/Examples/JAIN%20SIP

I am getting this exception:

[image: I am getting this exception:]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are connected to the WIFI or any other data connectivity, this exception is thrown when the SIP stack tries to find the remote end point (IP and Port pair) from the provided domain.